How to avoid server overwhelming when write log by winston in nodejs?
I have a Socket server which accept about 250000 connections as the same time.  So I need to create a Log function to save status and errors of each connections.
I used Winston to save logs and the worker_thread module to offload the logging process from the main thread.
I used a loop to write a million log lines in the worker_thread to verify if the main thread continues to process normally.
Unfortunately, the main thread becomes unresponsive during the logging process.
Does anyone know how to resolve the issue mentioned above?
const logQueue: Array<LogParams | (ErrorLogParams & { log_type: string })> = [];
const batchSize = 1000;
let processing = false;
let test = true;

/** */
function processLogQueue() {
    if (processing || logQueue.length === 0) return;
    processing = true;

    const batch = logQueue.splice(0, batchSize);
    batch.forEach((data) => {
        if (Libs.isBlank(data.log_type) || Libs.isBlank(data.message)) return;
        switch (data.log_type) {
        case 'info':
            FLLogger.info(data as LogParams);
            break;
        case 'warn':
            FLLogger.warn(data as LogParams);
            break;
        case 'error':
            FLLogger.error(data as ErrorLogParams);
            break;
        case 'critical':
            FLLogger.critical(data as ErrorLogParams);
            break;
        }
    });

    processing = false;

    // Process the next batch
    if (logQueue.length > 0) {
        setImmediate(processLogQueue);
    }
}

if (parentPort) {
    parentPort.on('message', (data: LogParams | (ErrorLogParams & { log_type: string })) => {
        logQueue.push(data);
        if (!processing) {
            setImmediate(processLogQueue);
        }
    });

    if (test) {
        test = false;
        for (let i=0; i< 10000000; i++) {
            logQueue.push({
                fileName: 'LogWorker',
                methodName: 'Stress test',
                message: `Test message ${i} - is main thread: ${isMainThread }`,
                deviceType: Constants.DEVICE_TYPE.SERVER,
                log_type: Constants.LOG_TYPE.WARN,
            });
        }
    }

    setInterval(() => {
        if (!processing && logQueue.length > 0) {
            setImmediate(processLogQueue);
        }
    }, 1000);
}


The code you've posted doesn't seem to be using worker_thread.

The above code handles logging in the worker thread. In the main thread, I create the worker thread using new Worker(path.resolve(__dirname, './LogWorker')) and use postMessage to send data to the worker for processing

You should show that too – or rather, isolate an MRE that shows the blocking behavior you're seeing.
